# Sonata installation error: "Non-existent parameter"

Tags: symfony, bundle, sonata-admin

**Context:**

Hello, I am working on a project and I need to set-up Symfony on the server.

The installation worked well, but now I need to install Sonata, and I got an error while doing it.

edit: I am using last version of Symfony and Sonata.

**Steps:**

I followed the [installation tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/getting_started/installation.html) on Sonata website. The installation command was : `composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle`. But when you install Sonata, you also need a "Storage bundle".

I chose the default one : "SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle". Then I went to their website to follow the [installation guide](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/installation.html).

When I try to download the bundle with this command: `composer require sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle`, I got an error.

**Error:**

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!
!!  In ParameterBag.php line 100:
!!                                                                              
!!    You have requested a non-existent parameter "sonata.admin.configuration.adm
!!    in_services".                                                             
!!                                                                              
!!
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

I tried to search solutions on the web, but I founded nothing. If someone could help me, I would be very grateful!

Comment: It seems that you use Symfony 3 (not 4). It's just the post-install scripts that fail, not the installation itself.

Have you enabled the bundle in your `config/bundles.php` file ?

Answer (score -1):

In config/bundles.php delete this line:

Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle::class => ['all' => true],